# can't see conent after moving to new server -

Tags: joomla

I'm on joomla 2.5 and have just moved to a new server. Have transfered files and databases and updated configuration.php. The problem is that I see no content and in the backend when entering global configuration or an artcle all I see is a blank page. When enabling errors I get

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strpos() in /home/wwwmyxol/public_html/myilioupolis.gr/templates/yoo_sync/layouts/module.php on line 118

Can you help please? Thank you

Comment: link: http://myxolargos.gr

Comment: This is a server related issue. Either contact your host or change the code to `JString::strpos()`

Comment: Can you be more specific on server issue? What could it be? Also where to change the code to JString::strpos() Thanks for helping

Comment: Personally I wouldnt edit any code, but talk to your host and get them to sort it out

Comment: You probably need to have the multibyte php extension enabled. Core Joomla does not assume it is present but yoo_sync may.